# Создать список и функцию удаления элемента из списка - C++

Tags: c++, список

Нужно удалить элемент из списка, который следует после каждого положительного элемента. Много лазил в инете, много пробовал, но всё без толку. Вообще не шарю как удалять эти элементы. Код прикрепил, всё работает кроме функции удаления. Можете помочь, пожалуйста? Буду признателен, если прикрепите комментарии к коду, чтоб разобраться как это делать.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct List
{
    int data, size;
    List *Head, *Next;
};
struct Node 
{
    int data;
    Node* Next;
};

void Make_List(int n, Node **Head)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        (*Head) = new Node;
        cout<<"Напишите число: ";
        cin>>(*Head) -> data;
        (*Head) -> Next = NULL;
        Make_List(n - 1, &((*Head) -> Next));
    }
}

void Show_List(Node *Head) 
{ 
    if (Head != NULL)
    {
        cout<<Head -> data<<"\t";
        Show_List(Head -> Next);
    }
    else cout<<"\n";
} 

void Delete_Item(List *Head, int n) 
{
     Node* curr = list -> Head; // Текущий элемент списка

while(curr != nullptr) // Проходим по списку
{
    if(curr -> data > 0) 
    {
        Node* tmp = curr -> Next; // удаляемый элемент
        curr -> Next = tmp -> Next; 

        delete tmp;
    }

    curr = curr -> Next;
}
} 


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale (0,".1251");

    Node *Head;
    int n;

    cout << "Введите размер списка: ";
    cin >> n;

    Make_List (n, &Head);
    Show_List (Head);
    Delete_Item (Head, n);
    Show_List (Head);

    system("pause"); 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того, что вы в корне не верно описали список. У вас каждый элемент списка является списком. Такого быть не должно. Список - структура данных, каждый элемент которой имеет значение(`data`) и указатель на следующий элемент(`next`).

```
struct List 
{
    int size;
    Node *Head;
};

struct Node 
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void deleteItems(List* list)
{
    Node* curr = list->Head; // Текущий элемент списка

    while(curr != nullptr) // Проходим по списку
    {
        if(curr->data % 2 == 0) // Если элемент четный
        {
            Node* tmp = curr->next; // удаляемый элемент
            curr->next = tmp->next; 

            delete tmp;
        }

        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

P.S. Раз уж вы пишите на C++, то советую вам использовать его преимущеста, как минимум классы и функции-члены

Comment: Спасибо, можно тогда ещё вопрос? У меня теперь в функциях создания и отображения списка подчёркивает data и Next. Как можно исправить, чтоб ещё больше не напартачить? Извинияюсь, если вопрос тупой, просто я только недавно начал изучать структуры в плане списков, стеков и т.д. А классы ещё не трогал.

Comment: @Идентикон в смысле подчеркивает?

Comment: Говорит, что List не содержит data и Next. Тогда надо в параметрах функций заменить List на Node?

Comment: @Идентикон Да, все, что относится к узлу списка заменить на `Node`

Comment: Сделал, только в этой строчке говорит, что List* и Node* несовместимы, подчёркивая Head
`Delete_Item (Head, n);`

Comment: Сейчас код полностью сюда отправлю, может и ошибся где-то

Comment: Исправил, но видимо снова коряво ._.

Comment: @Идентикон у вас все очень плохо в коде. Я завтра сделаю вам ревью, если никто до меня этого не сделает)

Comment: Буду вам премного благодарен!)

Comment: ну как там успехи?

Answer (score 0):

Если делать так, как делаете вы, тогда получится что-то [подобное](https://trycode.pw/KBBM2YX8).

---

Небольшое ревью:

1) В структуре `List` должно быть только то, что относится к списку, то есть размер и указатели на элементы (в случае односвязного списка только на первый)
2) В вашей функции `Make_List` вы передаете указатель по указателю, в результате вы повсюду вам приходится разыменовывать его и брать адрес, тем самым читаемость кода очень сильно убивается и не так очевидно то, что в ней происходит. Намного проще передать его по ссылке и избавиться он лишних телодвижений.
3) Вы повсюду для обхода списка используете рекурсию, но это может занимать достаточно много ресурсов и для того, чтобы сделать адекватный интерфейс приходится вводить дополнительные функции. В данном случае рекурсию лучше заменить на цикл (как я сделал в `Show_List`).

Ну и самое главное, большинство ваших проблем можно избежать, используя принципы ООП, вы же все таки программируете на `C++`, а не на `C`.

P.S. Если данный ответ решил вашу проблему, то пометьте его как ответ

Comment: Попробовал, в главном теле в функциях `Show_List` ругалось на `list`. Заменил на ваши доп. функции `_show_list`. Запускаю программу и при показе списка выдаёт ошибку и указывает на строчку в функции `Show_List` вот на эту `cout << node->data << "\t";` Ошибка примерно такая: в `Node` ошибка чтения памяти в `data` и `next`. А так уже более менее разобрался в коде, некоторые вещи прояснились. Надеюсь на Вашу поддержку, ибо она очень нужна!

Comment: @Идентикон Поправил. Не надо ничего заменять, просто копи-паст. Функции `Make_List` и `Show_List` просто вызывают функции `_make_list` и `_show_list` для первого элемента списка, а `_*`, в свою очередь, запускают рекурсию и создают/выводят весь оставшийся список